# R: how to smartbind multiple dataframes in a simpler way?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to use smartbind() to merge 20+ dataframes. 
These data frames have  different number of observations (rows). Most of their columns have the same names though some differ. I have named them like this:

```
data.Argentina  
data.Brazil  
data.Venezuela
```

Then, I wrote

```
library(gtools)
combined.data  <- smartbind(mget(ls(pattern = "^data.")))
```

The error information is :

> Error in data.frame(data.Argentina = list(pais = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
>   :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 1512, 3429, 1533, 3067,
>   1500, 1571, 1510, 1537, 1520, 1489, 1507, 1557, 1561, 1503, 1535,
>   1546, 1508, 4000, 4203

Then, I have to do it by manually **listing all data frames**:

```
combined.data <- smartbind (data.Argentina, data.Brazil, data.Venezuela)
```

**This time it works!**

So could I use other functions or other commands to make the process simpler?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you getting your `smartbind` function from? Be sure to include an non-default R packages you may be using. Also, it would help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is from gtools. I hope to provide an example but my data is too large to upload.

Comment: Surely you can provide an example with fake data then that reproduces your problem, no?

Answer (score 3):

Passing a bunch of arguments in a list is not the same as passing them separately. The `do.call` command can expand a list into different parameters. Try

```
combined.data <- do.call("smartbind", mget(ls(pattern = "^data.")))
```